# Finding the smallest number and largest number from a list of random numbers generated

Tags: c++

I'm new here and this forum has been a great help! Unfortunately, I'm not able to find the answer to my issue here or anywhere else on the web. I was hoping some of you can give me some help or tips on how to go about this.

The program will generate random numbers based on the max limit and the amount of random numbers that will generate.

I'm also required to find the smallest, largest number, as well as the average from all the numbers generated in the loop. The average I can find using the sum/MAX_COUNT_NUM. Unfortunately, I am stuck finding the smallest and largest number. Been at this for the past 6 hours. Please help anyway you can. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int UP_MAX, MAX_COUNT_NUM, RAND_NUM, MIN_COUNT_NUM;


cout << "This program creates random numbers" << "\n" << "\n";

cout << "Enter the upper limit of all generated random numbers: ";
cin >> UP_MAX;
cout << "\n" << "\n";
cout << "Enter the count of random numbers: ";
cin >> MAX_COUNT_NUM;
cout << "\n" << "\n";
cout << "Creating " << MAX_COUNT_NUM << " random numbers from 1 to " << UP_MAX << ": " << "\n" << "\n";

MIN_COUNT_NUM = 1;
int LARGE = 0;
int SMALL = 0;

for (; MAX_COUNT_NUM >= MIN_COUNT_NUM; MIN_COUNT_NUM++)
{
    RAND_NUM = rand() % UP_MAX + 1;
    cout << setw(8) << RAND_NUM;

    if (RAND_NUM < SMALL)
    {
        SMALL = UP_MAX + 1;
    }
    if (RAND_NUM > LARGE)
    {
        LARGE = RAND_NUM;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I need to do this without arrays and vectors. In my head, I'm thinking it should work as well but it doesn't. The largest number comes out fine, but the smallest comes out as 0 which makes me scratch my head.

I'm taking a beginners course and this got me stumped, so my way of thinking may be off beat. If there are any other tips you can provide, I definitely appreciate it.

Comment: `SMALL = UP_MAX + 1;` should be `SMALL = RAND_NUM ;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the initial values that you picked for `LARGE` and `SMALL`: you set both of them to `0`, which is incorrect: you should set them both to the first random number that you generate.

Alternatively, you can set `SMALL` to the *largest* possible `int`, and `LARGE` to the *smallest* possible `int`. Use `<limits>` header and [`std::numeric_limits<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class.

**Note:** `SMALL = UP_MAX + 1;` should be `SMALL = RAND_NUM;`

Comment: Thank you! I took your advice and it really helped!